# ScrollsToTop not working on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a `UITextView` inside of a `UITableView`. In the code, I set `textView.scrollEnabled = NO;`

When I run the project on iOS6, I can scroll to the top when I press to the status bar. However, when I run the project in iOS7, I could not manage to scroll top when it is pressed to the status bar. Could you please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Question is a little bit confusing, UITextField should not be scrollable. Only UITextView... Anyway, if you want to enable Scrolls to top on your UITableView, you should set tableView.scrollsToTop property to YES.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: even textField does not have a scrollEnabled property. please clear your question, or post a code what you are trying.

Comment: I meant UITextView but i wrote UITextField. Sorry

Comment: Are you setting your content size?

Comment: Yes. I tried to set contentSize. It did not work again.

Answer (score 4):

The correct property you should be using is:

```
textView.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

When you click the status bar, it will search throughout your views for UIScrollViews with that property as YES and scroll it to top.

I think that on iOS7 if there is more than one scrollView with that property as YES it will not do anything. So you need to set it to NO on all you don't want the behavior and just leave it as YES on the tableView if that is what you want to scroll on status bar touch.

UITextView and UITableView are both subclasses of UIScrollView so they all inherit that property and behavior. By default, all of them have it as YES (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: I tried but it did not work again. Somethings have wrong because this code worked on iOS 6

Comment: Have you tried setting your `UITableView` `scrollsToTop = YES;` ?

Comment: You really need to make sure ALL other scrollViews have scrollsToTop = NO, and that only the tableView has scrollsToTop = YES. If it is not working, it's because you forgot something. Think about all elements you have that might be a UIScrollView subclass, even the ones that are hidden.

Comment: plus 1 for the snippet of UITextView also has scrollsToTop. This is what was causing me my headache

Answer (score 0):

It is a good solution for iOS 7 :
http://ruiaureliano.tumblr.com/post/37260346960/uitableview-tap-status-bar-to-scroll-up

It worked in my project.